# One-time redirect upon detecting Nuxt PWA in standalone mode

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, nuxt.js

I'm trying to achieve this, but no luck.

Here's the plugin. All three console logs are running correctly, including the 3rd-party platform.js functionality.

It's just the `this.$route.router.go('/ourmenu')` that isn't doing the redirect. I'm wondering if this is the right way to redirect in Nuxt, or if it needs to be done differently.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

window.onNuxtReady(() => {

    console.log('onNuxtReady!');
    console.log('platform test: ');
    console.log(platform.os.toString())

    if (platform.os.toString().includes('iOS') == true && window.navigator.standalone == true) {
        this.$route.router.go('/ourmenu');
    } else if (window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches) {
        this.$route.router.go('/ourmenu');
    } else {}

})
```

EDIT: I've also tried `this.$router.push('/ourmenu')` and `context.redirect(`${config.url}/ourmenu`)`

...Still a no go.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found a much more simple solution: 
[Web App Manifest: start_url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest/start_url)

[Nuxt PWA Docs](https://pwa.nuxtjs.org/modules/manifest.html)